# pipeline processing of onehot encoding

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to USE SKLearn.pipeline to streamline the process.
the Issue is I am doing one-hot encoding inside the pipeline for categorical data. while doing `pipeline.fit()` I have more number of features since as the result of one-hot encoding the number of features increased but while doing `pipeline.predict()` I am getting very fewer features because one-hot encoding produces fewer columns due to the less number of categories mentioned in it.
so I am getting below exception:

> ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input.
> Model n_features is 291 and input n_features is 281

kindly suggest how to overcome this issue.

```
class handleCategory(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self,X,y=None):
        X_=X.copy()
        X_=pd.get_dummies(X_)
        return X_

class handleImputation(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    imputationProcessedColGlobal=[]
    def __init__(self):
        print("init")
        pass
    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        print('fit')
        return self
    def transform(self,X,y=None):
        print('transform')
        X_=X.copy()
        data_len=X_.shape[0]
        columnsToDrop=[]
        for i in X_.columns:
            if X_[i].isnull().sum()>data_len*0.7:
                columnsToDrop.append(i)
        imputationProcessedCol= [i for i in X_.columns if not i in columnsToDrop]
        imputationProcessedColGlobal=imputationProcessedCol[:]
        #X_=X_[imputationProcessedCol]
        for i in X_.columns:
            if X_[i].isnull().sum()>0 : 
                if X_[i].dtype=="object":
                    print("imputation hanlded for col "+str(i) +" sum "+str(X_[i].isnull().sum()))
                    X_[i+'_missing']=X_[i].isnull()
                    X_[i].fillna(X_[i].mode().iloc[0])
                else:
                    print("imputation hanlded for col "+str(i) +" sum "+str(X_[i].isnull().sum()))
                    X_[i+'_missing']=X_[i].isnull()
                    X_[i].fillna(X_[i].mean(),inplace = True)
           
        return X_


gbr_params = {'n_estimators': 1000,
          'max_depth': 3,
          'min_samples_split': 5,
          'learning_rate': 0.01,
          'loss': 'ls'}
#
# Create an instance of gradient boosting regressor
#
gbr = GradientBoostingRegressor(**gbr_params)
pipeline1.fit(train_data,trainY)
testY=pipeline1.predict(test_data)
```

while executing pipeline1.predict(test_data) it is throwing the number of feature miss-match exceptions.

Comment: Can you show your pipeline?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel added the pipeline.

Comment: Why not use [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) from scikit-learn? You can set parameters to handle unknowns

Comment: I also want to add the imputation column for missing entry of the  feature, can that be done via onehotencoder??

Comment: Scikit-learn has different [imputers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.impute).